# Magento Observer not doing much observing

Tags: php, model-view-controller, magento, observer-pattern, mage

So this is my first module, so I figured there would be errors.  But I am stuck and thought the intelligence of the stack overflow community could help out.

Essentially I want my module to listen for the event of a catalog search index update and perform some code based on that.

So I told magento to recognize my module in:

**app/etc/modules/Nate_SearchToFind.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Nate_SearchToFind>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Nate_SearchToFind>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Then in: **app/local/Nate/SearchToFind/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <global>
    <models>
        <natesearchtofindbundle>
             <class>Nate_SearchToFind_Bundle_Model</class>
        </natesearchtofindbundle>
    </models>
    <events>
        <catalogindex_plain_reindex_after>
            <observers>
                 <Nate_SearchToFind_Observer>
                     <type>singleton</type>
                     <class>Nate_SearchToFind_Bundle_Model_Observer</class>
                     <method>beautify_search</method>
                 </Nate_SearchToFind_Observer>
             </observers>
        </catalogindex_plain_reindex_after>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

Then in: **app/code/local/Nate/SearchToFind/Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php
class Nate_SearchToFind_Bundle_Model_Observer
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    public function beautify_search($observer)
    {
        //perform function operations here
    }
}
```

Does anyone spot some errors in my code (I'm sure they are in there) or as my approach as a whole, but I cannot seem to find them...Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your observer class name is wrong.  It should be `Nate_SearchToFind_Model_Observer` in the PHP class file and the XML observer section.

Class names in the Zend Framework follow the directory structure. The class prefix you are trying to use, `Nate_SearchToFind_Bundle_Model`, actually refers to files in `app/code/{core,local,community}/Nate/SearchToFind/Bundle/Model`, I believe.  It needs to be changed to `Nate_SearchToFind_Model` to reflect your current directory structure.

You're also defining the class prefix, but not using it.  For example, the `<class></class>` section of the observer section could read `<class>natesearchtofindbundle/observer</class>`, which would map to `Nate_SearchToFind_Model_Observer`, assuming you aligned the prefix with your directory structure.